# How to launch the Google Play Store as a popup

Tags: android, google-play, ads

I've seen ads that display app stores as a popup rather than as a full screen view.

For Samsung Galaxy Store, I recently learned that this can be achieved if the url contains a query parameter with "form=popup". Does anyone know of a similar thing for the Google Play Store, either as part of the Intent or the Url?

Example:
[image: Blackout Bingo - Samsung Galaxy Store]